# Hibernate - How to read non-locked rows without locking them

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve a list of rows from a table, excluding all rows that have a "SELECT FOR UPDATE"-style lock on them. If I use UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED as LockMode I get the correct result, but as far as I have understood this uses a stronger lock than what I need (which would be a sort of READ_SKIPLOCKED mode, if it existed).

Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks for the help in advance!